# How to use `python3-autopilot` with `python3 -m venv venv`?

Tags: package-management, python3

**How can I use `python3-autopilot` with `python3 -m venv venv`?**

I have installed `python3-autopilot` (Ubuntu's "Utility to write and run integration tests easily") with `sudo apt-get install -y python3-autopilot`.

Although I would prefer to install `python3-autopilot` with `pip install`.

Note: [`autopilot` on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/autopilot/) *is not* `python3-autopilot`.

- [`python3-autopilot` is version 1.6.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/python3-autopilot) and [`autopilot` on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/autopilot/) is only version 0.3.0 and appears to be a completely different package.
- Before `python3 -m venv venv` and `. ./venv/bin/activate`, I can `from autopilot.input import Mouse`, but without packages from my virtual env.
- After `. ./venv/bin/activate`, `from autopilot.input import Mouse` says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autopilot'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The package's README says](https://git.launchpad.net/autopilot/tree/README?id=6f8cf5b650e4a67426cf2488b23e9055ae3a1fbb):

> Autopilot is not buildable within a python virtualenv, as it requires several packages that are not available on `pypi`. Instead, either use autopilot from the source tree, or build debian packages instead.

So it seems the package is intentionally not available from PyPI, and therefore `pip install` won't work, by default. There might be a way using custom sources, I'm not sure, but the "use from source tree" option seemed to work for me:

1. `git clone -b master https://git.launchpad.net/autopilot` into your project's directory.
2. Move the actual package directory up (the Python files you actually need):

   - `mv autopilot/ autopilot-src/`
   - `mv autopilot-src/autopilot/ ./autopilot/`
3. Activate your `venv`. Assuming it's in the current directory: `. venv/bin/activate`.
4. Install some required dependencies: `pip install psutil decorator testtools`. (I identified these by trial and error.)
5. The package can now be used. In `python` I'm able to do `from autopilot.input import Mouse`.

Notes:

- Although I've tested this up until successfully importing the package within my `venv`, I can't say if it won't throw up errors when you actually use it.

  - You're sort of going against the intended environment of this package, which appears to be the Ubuntu/Debian system Python env. Note that the `apt` package has many other dependencies, even non-Python ones.
  - On that note, I did `sudo apt install python3-autopilot` before the steps above and it's possible that *that* installed some dependencies that the package will still depend on. Even with `venv` we can't be guaranteed that the package won't need some system (non-Python) dependencies.
- This approach means you can't simply add the package to your virtual environment's `requirements.txt`, so you have to document the special instructions if you want others to be able to reproduce your env.

Answer (score 1):

You can use venv's parameter `--system-site-packages` to use the autopilot installed by apt.

```
python3 -m venv --system-site-packages venv
. venv/bin/activate
python
```

```
>>> from autopilot.input import Mouse
>>>
```